# Time loop for WooCommerce checkout select option

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, woocommerce, checkout

I need your help please.
I have time picker on my WordPress site, it looks like this:

[image]

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'time', array(
   'type'        => 'select',
   'label'       => __('Delivery Time', 'woocommerce'),
   'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
   'required'    => 'true',
   'options'     => array(
      '9 AM - 10 AM' => __('9 AM - 10 AM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '10 AM - 11 AM' => __('10 AM - 11 AM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '11 AM - 12 PM' => __('11 AM - 12 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '12 PM - 1 PM' => __('12 PM - 1 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '1 PM - 2 PM' => __('1 PM - 2 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '2 PM - 3 PM' => __('2 PM - 3 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '3 PM - 4 PM' => __('3 PM - 4 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '4 PM - 5 PM' => __('4 PM - 5 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '5 PM - 6 PM' => __('5 PM - 6 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '6 PM - 7 PM' => __('6 PM - 7 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '7 PM - 8 PM' => __('7 PM - 8 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '8 PM - 9 PM' => __('8 PM - 9 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '9 PM - 10 PM' => __('9 PM - 10 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '10 PM - 11 PM' => __('10 PM - 11 PM', 'woocommerce' ),
      '11 PM - 12 AM' => __('11 PM - 12 AM', 'woocommerce' )
   ),
), $checkout->get_value( 'time' ));
```

However I want options are based on some rules:
 1. If client choose todays date on date picker, no options will be avalible.
 2. If client will choose tomorrows date, it will show options(Current Time + 24hours) 
 3. If client will choose date after tomorrow, all options will be avalible.

Please, I need your help.
Thank you.